# Declaring multiple arrays in PHP with one line

Tags: php, array

Is it possible to declare multiple arrays in PHP in one line?

```
$userAnswers  = array();
$questionIDs = array ();
$sqlAnswers = array();
$sqlAnswersQuery = array();
$correctAnswers = array();
```

Any cleaner ways of doing this?

NOTE: The contents of these arrays are all DIFFERENT. I don't think setting them equal to each other would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way. Wether you like it or not is another question:

```
$userAnswers = $questionIDs = $sqlAnswers = $sqlAnswersQuery = $correctAnswers = array();
```

I'm **not a fan** of this. This isn't easy to read, especially for the-new-guy-who-doesn't-know-this-code. This works for small amounts of variables, *but even then with caution*:

```
$hasErrors = $hasWarnings = false;
```

---

I think the way you should declare the variables as array depends on how you set the first values, we can't see enough code to answer based on that.

Comment: All of my arrays are going to have different contents, would setting them equal to each other make them have all the same contents?

Comment: Nope, it's not `by reference`, you just all set them to the last value of the line. But again, your current method is a better plan. Just add a few spaces to line up the equation signs, will be enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is good as it is.
It's recommended to have one statement per line, for better readability:
code is easier to read when the logic flows from top to bottom,
with no distractions sideways.
So even if there was a way to do this on one line, you really shouldn't.